# Adding reference aspx page from same project, in another current working aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I have dropdownlist1 (ddlseats) in one aspx page.But I want the value of that dropdownlist1 in another aspx page.How to achieve that?By doing R & D, I got to know that by adding reference we could achieve.But how to add aspx page where dropdownlist1 contains, to the present working aspx page of same project.I want to see ddlseats in IntelliSense where am working (Present aspx page).
Please help me.

Comment: you can't do that, try passing the dropdownlist value by query string, or session

Comment: Thanks Waqas Raja, that works for me.